# After Pushing a Array Element in react.js using useState and useEffect it's looping infinite after update the state. How to solve?

Tags: reactjs

I have push some a image elements in object array it's working fine but how to update the state?

```
const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    
        const postsMap = posts.map(post => {
            return {...post, "image": `image-${post.id}.jpg`}
        })
    
        console.log("Added Post Image", postsMap);
    
        useEffect(()=>{
            fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setPosts(data)
                console.log(data);
            })
            
        }, [postsMap]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say its because -

- `setPosts(data)` in `useEffect()` updates post
- update in post updates `postsMap`
- update in `postsMap` triggers a re-render of the component
- repeat the cycle.

I think the infinite loop is probably because of the wrong parameter passed to the dependency array provided to `useEffect` as the second parameter. I think passing an empty array as a parameter to useEffect's second argument should solve the problem.

Comment: Empty array as a parameter to useEffect's second argument doesn't give the updated state that I push the Image in array object

Comment: @JoneySpark Does your test-editor give any warning/suggestion as to what needs to be passed in dep array? I usually stick to it & most times it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Because your useEffect is dependend on a variable that changes within it self (setPosts). So you create an infinite Loop. You don’t need postmap as dependency, use url as dependency.

Comment: url is only the API link but I get all value in posts and after I map the post and push the image element on the array object and store in postsMap so url not chage the state here

Comment: postsMap changes after you set the state of posts in useEffect. useEffect fires if you change postsMap. This creates an infinite loop. If you only want to force to rerender you can try a second useEffect with no content, but postsMap as dependency

Comment: I try it but the empty useEffect with postsMap dependency is not set my updated state where I push the image in the array object